# Regex for adding thousand separator WITHOUT decimals?

Tags: javascript, regex, separator

I need a regular expression for adding a dot as a thousand and millon separator in Javascript. I've searched the whole web without finding the format I need.
It would return this:

```
1
12
123
1.234
12.345
123.456
1.234.567
12.345.678
123.456.789
```

I'm trying to use it in an input.

```
  handleIdChange = (personalIdNumber) => {
this.validator.updateField("personalId", {
  number: personalIdNumber
})
this.props.setVisitorField({
  field: "personalId.number",
  value: personalIdNumber
});

            <CLTextInput
            highContrast={true}
            onChangeText={this.handleIdChange}
            keyboardType="numeric"
            placeholder="Número"
            returnKeyType="next"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            autoCorrect={false}
            value={visitor.personalId.number}
            error={this.shouldShowError("personalId")}
            accessibility
            />
```

Comment: ... or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript, lots of solutions out there

Comment: Take any of the good answers from the duplicate, and just use dot as the replacement instead of comma.

Comment: There's also the option of not using regex, and going with [Number.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: none of those answers worked for me. They return 1.1.123, 1.1.1.123 and so on.

Comment: If you insist on using a regex for this, this should work: `"123456789".replace(/(.)(?=(.{3})+$)/g, "$1.")`

Comment: The one Jay proposed returns 4..6.5.435

Comment: Are you sure you're using javascript and keeping the expression as it is? My expression works perfectly for me and since it dictates that a "character must be followed by a multiple of 3 characters until the end" to be considered a match... I see no way how it could output "4..6.5.435" in any scenario. What was your input? Maybe it had . characters already in it?

Comment: I'm trying to use it in an input. Just added more details to the question

Comment: @AmadeodelaPeña I think the problem is that you are running the regex in a CHANGE handler so the Regex replacement triggers another Regex replacement.
Make sure to remove existing dots before! basically `.replace(/\./g,'').replace(/(.)(?=(.{3})+$)/g, "$1.")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244666/discussion-between-amadeo-de-la-pena-and-jay).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regular expressions to format numbers. Use a proper number formatter.

If you want german-style number formatting, set that as the locale.

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const number = 10 ** i;
    console.log(formatter.format(number));
}
```

Comment: This returns NaN when used in a handleChange in an input :/

Comment: @AmadeodelaPeña — Perhaps you are feeding it a string and you need to use `parseInt` first.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's writing it back to the input, which triggers another "handleChange" and now the already formatted value with dots, which is NaN is fed to the formatter.